# Dual Boot Windows 10 / Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, mount

I've done this a lot of times and it worked normally but this time there's a little difference:

- I got by normal windows 10 and ubuntu 15.04 dual booting with grub and all.
- I installed CentOS 7 instead of Ubuntu and still everything was fine.
- Finally installed Ubuntu 15.04 instead of CentOS 7 and re-activated grub, but I don't get the windows 10 bootloader anymore.

Output from boot-repair : http://paste.ubuntu.com/12879443/

output from `sudo fdisk -l` is:

```
Device          Start        End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1        2048    2050047   2048000  1000M Windows recovery environment
/dev/sda2     2050048    2582527    532480   260M EFI System
/dev/sda3     2582528    4630527   2048000  1000M unknown
/dev/sda4     4630528    4892671    262144   128M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sda5     4892672  941965311 937072640 446.9G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda6   941965312 1559795711 617830400 294.6G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda7  1559795712 1575837695  16041984   7.7G Linux swap
/dev/sda8  1575837696 1607923711  32086016  15.3G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda9  1607923712 1926801407 318877696 152.1G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda11 1926801408 1953523711  26722304  12.8G Windows recovery environment
```

Finally the Ubuntu Menu is still showing 3 Hard Disks: LRS_ESP (opens directories after click) , Windows8_OS & Backup (which are 2 other partitions but they don't function on click anymore)

What could the problem possibly be? Because I don't think the windows partitions got formatted in the middle of this.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to re-install grub and then grub will automatically find out which operating systems can be booted from. If this doesn't work, some of the partitions that can be booted should have a "boot"-flag. Check with e.g. gparted. I suggest boot from a live USB/DVD/CD and run gparted - also from the live system, mount your NTFS Windows partition - check that everything is ok. Then if everything fails, I would run the Windows install disk (knowingly, this will overwrite grub). Then you get to the point where, whenever you reboot Windows will start. And when you're here, you're almost home - THEN you run grub (from live-dvd/cd/usb) and then I'm absolutely sure that it'll find Windows and your other operating systems... I've tried this many times also. I think you'll succeed with this methodology...